# Using preg_match on my nav to add active state

Tags: php

I'm not too good with php, just the basics. So i'm using php to add the active states to my navigation links and using css after to style them, I was wondering if theres a way to use hashtags. I have two different navigation links that are both on one page. The first one works fine because no # is used but the second since the info for that page is on the same page as the default, I have the following code:

```
<?php
if (preg_match ("//", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){ $navID = "home";} 
if (preg_match ("/service-area/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){ $navID = "service";} 
if (preg_match ("/about/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){ $navID = "about";} 
    if (preg_match ("/heating-air/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){ $navID = "heating";} 
if (preg_match ("/plumbing-hvac/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){ $navID = "plumbing";} 
?>
```

Theres the pregmatch and here are the links:

```
<ul class="right-nav">
            <li class="heating-air"><a href="/plumbing-hvac/#heating-air" <?= ($navID == 'heating') ? ' class="active"' : '' ?>>Plumbing</a></li>   
            <li class="plumbing"><a href="/plumbing-hvac/" <?= ($navID == 'plumbing') ? ' class="active"' : '' ?>>Heating &amp; Air</a></li>
        </ul>
```

I get an error whenever I add the anchor link to the `preg_match()` section. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part starting with `#` in an URL is never transfered to the server, so `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` won't include it.

So regardless of the error you get, it won't make any sense to look for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-complicating things, you can just use `strpos` instead of a regular expression:

```
$navID = "home";
$navID = (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'service-area') !== false) ? 'service' : $navID;
//etc
```

Note that the first line is for clarity, you can just put `home` in the second line as well.